# php variable pass to javascript using getJSON()

Tags: javascript, php

i want to pass a php variable to javascript

on php(getStatus.php) i'm using json_encode like this

```
$resultFin = array();
if (strpos($status,'Scan is complete') === true){
$resultFin[] = 1;
}
else{ 
    $resultFin[] = 0;
}

echo json_encode($resultFin);
echo "$status";
```

and i want get resultFin value on javascript so i wrote below code

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.post("scanner/getStatus.php", {testId:' . "$testId" . ',chkCnt:' . "$chkCount" . ',rxss:' . "$rxss" . ',sxss:' . "$sxss" . ',sqli:' . "$sqli" . ',basqli:' . "$basqli" . ',autoc:' . "$autoc" . ',idor:' . "$idor" . ',dirlist:' . "$dirlist" . ',bannerdis:' . "$bannerdis" . ',sslcert:' . "$sslcert" . ',unredir:' . "$unredir" . ',clamav:' . "$clamav" . '}, function(data){$("#status").html(data)});
     var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
$.post("scanner/getStatus.php", {testId:' . "$testId" . ',chkCnt:' . "$chkCount" . ',rxss:' . "$rxss" . ',sxss:' . "$sxss" . ',sqli:' . "$sqli" . ',basqli:' . "$basqli" . ',autoc:' . "$autoc" . ',idor:' . "$idor" . ',dirlist:' . "$dirlist" . ',bannerdis:' . "$bannerdis" . ',sslcert:' . "$sslcert" . ',unredir:' . "$unredir" . ',clamav:' . "$clamav" . '}, function(data){$("#status").html(data)});
console.log("dfdfdf");
$.getJSON("scanner/getStatus.php", function(data){
        var fini;
        fini = data;
        console.log(fini);
        if( fini == 1){
            clearInterval(refreshId);
            }
        });
}, 500);
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});</script>';
```

i have checked it using brakepoint console.log("dfdfd");

but not getting into getJSON method and don't get resultFin value

how to fix this code?

i want resultFin value using in javascript

Comment: Set value of $resultFin in HTML hidden input and access it on javascript side

Comment: When you echo status after you echo your json encoded $resultFin, you are essentially corrupting your json.

Answer (score 1):

Your getStatus.php should look like:

```
$resultFin = array();
if (strpos($status,'Scan is complete') === true){
$resultFin['scan_completed'] = true;
}
else{ 
    $resultFin['scan_completed'] = false;
}

echo json_encode($resultFin);
```

So on frontend you can use `fini.scan_completed` which will be true or false.

Comment: or just `$resultFin = ['scan_completed' => strpos($status,'Scan is complete') === true]`